# How can I give a custom service application to a content database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-2013

I've got a custom service application that looks at a site collection and stamps pdf's on that site collection.

The problem is that the application pool that the service applications runs as doesn't have access to the site collection's database.

It's easy enough to manually grant it access but if the farm admins create another content database the service application will not have access to that database.  I would like to be able to check which web applications use the service application and ensure the relevant accounts have access to the appropriate content databases.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are two things that you can do, depending on what you need. One is, on database level, you can guaranty your service application account Shell Admin permission using `Add-SPShellAdmin` - this might be helpful, if you need to make some administrative-like changes on database itself (not recommended) or iis/file system.

Second thing, that i expect will more fit to your need, but which works on webapplication level, is creating [User Policy on Web Application](http://www.thesharepointblog.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15), where you can grant your service account read-write access to all documents.

Please let know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: I definitely do not want to give Shell access to the account.
The option to use user policies is a bit nicer than having to add permissions to the database directly.
However, I wanted to know if it was possible to have this setup without further work and process the farm admin needs to know about.
I can't think of any OOB service applications that actually write to the content databases so there isn't a pattern to follow.

Comment: I think there aren't any that are writing, but this pattern - User Policy is used for Search Application (crawler) for reading from content databases.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I got pulled off this one for a while.
A user policy doesn't work because that simply gives permission within the SharePoint API.  I need the user to be added to the database directly.